# What do the different numbers and colors on the Flink dashboard represent?

Tags: apache-flink

When I log in to the Flink dashboard, to the right of every job, under the heading `Tasks`, there are number of coloured boxes with different numbers in them. What do they represent? I can't seem to find this information anywhere on the internet!

For reference, this is what I'm talking about -

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These indicators show the tasks (operators) that a parallel pipeline consists of.

- If you run a Flink job with a simple map function using a parallelism of 1, one task is executed in the cluster.
- If you run a Flink job with a simple map function using a parallelism of 2, two tasks are executed in the cluster.
- If you run a Flink job with a two map function using a parallelism of 1, two tasks are executed in the cluster.

The colors show the total number of tasks and the state of each task (in this order):

- total number of tasks
- created
- scheduled
- deploying
- running
- finished
- canceling
- canceled
- failed
- reconciling

See also [JobStatus class](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/jobgraph/JobStatus.java) for more information.